# Databinding with User Control not working for button background image source

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have added a user control to App.xml

```
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource PlayerButtonsStyle}"
            Width="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=ImageWidth}"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=ImageHeight}">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=Image}" />
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

In my main window I add following to add the button. And this does not display the image which I have added as a resource.

```
<local:ImageButton HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Height="25"
                   Margin="474,430,0,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Width="25"
                   Image="images/play.png">
</local:ImageButton>
```

But if I do following the image will display but this defeats the purpose of making it as a user control.

```
<local:ImageButton HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Height="25"
                   Margin="474,430,0,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Width="25"
                   Image="images/forward.png">
    <local:ImageButton.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/play.png"/>
    </local:ImageButton.Background>
</local:ImageButton>
```

Here is the User Control

```
public partial class ImageButton : UserControl
{
    public ImageButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Image.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public double ImageWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ImageWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageWidth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageWidth", typeof(double), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(16d));

    public double ImageHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ImageHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageHeight.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageHeight", typeof(double), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(16d));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

The style definition

```
<Style x:Key="PlayerButtonsStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>-->
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="3" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True" >
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of the UserControl, e.g. the declaration of the Image property.

Comment: I added the user control to post.

Comment: What's the purpose of this UserControl? Does it only have the Button?

Comment: It should display an image instead of a text and I have several buttons that should be the same but with different images.

Comment: No idea what's wrong. Your UserControl, i.e. `<ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=Image}"/>` works fine for me, without your PlayerButtonsStyle of course, because you haven't shown it. Perhaps that Style sets a ControlTemplate which ignores the Button's Background.

Comment: I tried to remove the style that did not change anything. I will add the style to the post.

Comment: I found several samples for this but could not get any to work in my project (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/knom/2007/10/31/wpf-control-development-3-ways-to-build-an-imagebutton/ and http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/01/create-wpf-image-button-through-attached-properties )

Instead I found Syncfusion and will be using their community edition which has the button type I need.